# Javascript: Changing a div's background color to a random color on mouseover

Tags: javascript, random, colors, background, onmouseover

I am relatively new to Javascripting and I am aware that there are answers related to this technique, however nowhere have I been able to get all the pieces.

On a webpage, I have created a 10 by 10 grid consisting of 100 identically-sized individual divs.
When any div is moused-over I want it to display a random background color (mousing across divs, a trail of differently colored divs would be displayed).

Within any given div, the function "fnPickColor" (which creates a color) is activated in this way:

```
onmouseover ="fnPickColor()"
```

My problem is: having generated the color, I do not know how to put it into the individual div which called the function. I cannot use "getElementById" or the tag-based references since these refer to specific individual divs or groups of them, not to whichever div is currently being moused-over.

I attempted a construct using "this.style.backgroundColor" to transfer the color, however that failed.

I'm sure it's extremely simple - how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

```
onmouseover = fnPickColor(this)
```

Then inside the function, use

```
this.style
```

**EDIT** I should not have tried to answer yesterday when I didn't have time to elaborate. I was thinking of something more like what David suggested.

I forgot the quotation marks

```
onouseover = "fnPickColor(this)"
```

and I should have clarified that you need to accept this in the function like this

```
function fnPickColor(what) {
    what.style.background = <YOUR RANDOM GENERATED COLOR>
}
```

you indicated that you already had the code to get the color.

Comment: this will call the function when the script is ran instead onmouseover

Comment: will it? Because I inadvertently used this inside the function instead of using a different name for the passed in value?

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate your effort. I see how the transference works now.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
.slider {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px black solid;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: all 0.75s ease-in-out;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
div class="slider" data-bind="style:{'background-color':color}, event:{mouseover:changeColor}"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    var attr = {
        color: ko.observable("azure"),
        changeColor: changeColor    
    };

    function changeColor() {
        attr.color("#" + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16));
        toastr.info(attr.color());
    }

    ko.applyBindings(attr);
})();
```

**Demo:**

click:
http://jsfiddle.net/samuelbigas/JZ4UX/2/

hover:
http://jsfiddle.net/samuelbigas/JZ4UX/4/

knockout:
http://jsfiddle.net/samuelbigas/JZ4UX/7/

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm finding that each of the submissions is adding to my understanding of various approaches to the question and I'm playing with them all. It's really quite flexible, as regards solutions, isn't it?

Comment: My favorite is http://jsfiddle.net/samuelbigas/JZ4UX/7/, knockout is very powerfull you should use it...

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div onmouseover="randomColor(this)"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
randomColor = function(e) {
    e.style.background =  "#" + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eptFf/

Comment: Works great at js fiddle, and with multiple divs there, too.

HOWEVER, despite having tried it meticulously, simple as it is, about 15 times in my own project, nothing happens. The div onmouseover does access the function - I put an alert just inside the curly braces to verify that) but the main line of the function doesn't run. 

Interestingly, I transferred the alert to a position directly after the code, and it (the alert) doesn't appear - which usually betokens that something was wrong with the material directly prior.
I have written out the code carefully - what can account for this?

Comment: I edited my answer. Math.Random() should have been Math.random(), incase you copied my answer, that may have been the problem. If that wasn't the problem, I'm not too sure what the problem could be. I made a simple page using the code I posted. Here's a link: http://hastebin.com/yedaworuye.xml

Comment: Yes! That was all it was. Thanks for checking, the matrix effect works perfectly now, as envisioned. I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

```
function rg(m, n) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * (n - m + 1) ) + m;
}

function hex(i) {
    return i.toString(16);
}

function randColor() {
    return '#' + hex(rg(1, 15)) + hex(rg(1, 15)) + hex(rg(1, 15)) +
        hex(rg(1, 15)) + hex(rg(1, 15)) + hex(rg(1, 15));
}

$(".subContent").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color",randColor());
});
```

I have create it parts so that you can reuse it. Hope you will get benefit.
http://jsfiddle.net/user007/yK7kq/1/

Comment: Appreciate your input very much. A few approaches have been submitted and I'm experimenting with this one too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example: [Random Color Generator](https://jsfiddle.net/talon4567/x61vee25/)

```
    function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
var div = document.getElementById( 'colorchange' );
div.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
  var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName( 'div' );
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
};
div.onmouseout = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName( 'h2' );
};
```